# Errors when running npm run build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, terminal, build

Im trying to create my built folder for a react project, but I get this error when I run the command 'npm run build'

```
(base) tazar@Tazs-Air nft-minter-tutorial-main % npm run build
npm ERR! Missing script: "build"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/tazar/.npm/_logs/2022-02-25T01_15_14_544Z-debug.log
```

Comment: In your package.json file, is the build command defined?

Comment: Likely not. `To see a list of scripts, run: npm run`.

Comment: "build": "react-scripts build" is present in my "scripts" if that what ur asking, but its still giving me the same error lines :( , gosh I hate node

Answer (score 2):

in your package.json file add build script, for example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check standard react package.json(which is located in root folder of your project) file:

```
{
  "name": "print",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If your answer is check whether "build": "react-scripts build" is present in my scripts, unfortunately it is, but it's still making my life a living hell and NOT making the damn build folder :) . Sorry bout my tone, it's just been frustrating me all day

Comment: Try also to make a `npm i react-scripts --save-dev`. In order to make sure it's installed. Also option to try if setting the output.path in webpack.config.js to an absolute path

`module.exports = {
    entry: ['./app/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If the build is defined in your package.json file, make sure that you are executing the 'npm run build' in the correct folder hierarchy( use 'cd' with no arguments or 'pwd').

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while running the command

```
npm run build
```

What I found was that I was running the command in the wrong folder and hence the error was sited. When I moved to the folder of my main project, and ran the same command it worked perfectly.
I think you are making the same mistake.
For eg:
If you have created a folder new_project, and then have created the react app in the folder(new_project) say, npx create-react-app project_folder

Then you must always run the command

```
npm run build
```

in this particular folder.